# Proportionality and Linearity

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have a very basic question that a friend and I are disagreeing on.

Does (direct) proportionality between two terms a and b imply linearity between the two terms?

Comment: what about `a` proportional to $b^2$? It does not imply linearity.

Comment: If a is proportional to (b^2), then a is linear to (b^2), right?

Comment: For the record, I suggested an edit improving the format and removing the tag "linear-algebra", but [it was rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2001400).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $a$ is directly proportional to $b$ means that $a = k b$ for some $k$.  This is a linear relationship.  Imagine something like force and acceleration.  If I double the force on an object, I double the acceleration.  If I have two different forces acting on an object, the effect is the same as one bigger force corresponding to the addition.

Comment: Could this be said to be a valid proof?

a is proportional to b implies a = kb
a(b) = kb
a(b+C) = a(c) + a(b)
a(cb) = c*a(b)

Comment: @Jacob: No proof of anything is required: that’s the **definition** of $a$ *is directly propertional to* $b$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott my friend addressed this by saying that I was saying that "G=C*B where B=1/r^2" (talking about gravity). and then went on to say that I "just defeated the whole purpose of a functional dependence.". Could you possibly help me understand what he means by functional dependence in this case?

Comment: I think what he means is that, G is proportional to B instead of 1/r^2. But B=1/r^2 implies that G is proportional to B and hence in turn proportional to 1/r^2. Hence the functional dependence still holds.

Comment: @Jacob: The way in which one quantity depends on another. Gravitational attraction is directly proportional to $\frac1{r^2}$, but that tells you how it depends on $\frac1{r^2}$. You’re more likely to be interested in its dependence on $r$: it’s inversely (because of the reciprocal) proportional to $r^2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks. this is what I thought, and I'm glad I don't have to go through re-thinking all of math now. if somehow proportionality was a different definition, I think I would be awfully confused.

Comment: @lsp that's what I think too. I also don't think that functional dependence means that my point is incorrect.